# Убрать символы в src картинки

Tags: javascript

Привет.
Имеется картинка, необходимо убрать в пути к картинке -300x214, при том что если картинка маленького размера не происходит ресайз изображения.

```
<img src="http://example.ru/01/kmg05-300x214.jpg" class="attachment-portfolio-three" alt="kmg05">
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var img = $('.attachment-portfolio-three');
var source = img.attr('src');
if (source.toLowerCase().indexOf("-300x214") >= 0)
{
    source = source.replace("-300x214", "");
    img.attr("src", source);
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8NSST/5/

или даже так

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var img = $('.attachment-portfolio-three');
var source = img.attr('src');
var str = "-300x214";
if (source.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) >= 0)
{
    source = source.replace(str, "");
    img.attr("src", source);
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8NSST/6/

**UPD**
Если нужно убирать `-300x214` из разных изображений с одним и тем же классом `.attachment-portfolio-three`, то тогда код такой

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var img$ = $('.attachment-portfolio-three');
var str = "-300x214";
img$.each(function () {
    var source = $(this).attr('src');
    if (source.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) >= 0) {
        source = source.replace(str, "");
        $(this).attr("src", source);
    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8NSST/9/

Answer (score 6):

Можно поступить более универсально и без jQuery, на случай если размер изменится:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.attachment-portfolio-three');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, function(img){
  img.src = img.src.replace(/-\d{2,4}x\d{2,4}/, '');
});
```

Comment: Рабочая шутка, только почему та последний в последнем товаре категорий не меняет путь картинки.